# CodeIgniter variable data/ value not passing to the view from the Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to echo out a variable value in the CodeIgniter view file. But when I run the site with...

```
<?php echo $highcharts; ?>
```

...on line 108, in the view, it gives an error. Please help me to echo out the value, so I can use it in HighCharts.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: highcharts
Filename: reports/bqt_daily_income_view.php
Line Number: 108
```

**This is my Controller:**

```
function bqt_daily_income() {

    $json_data = array();
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT time_stamp,  SUM(paid) AS income  FROM payments WHERE type = 'Banquet Reservation' GROUP BY time_stamp ORDER BY time_stamp ASC LIMIT 30");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {
    $json_data['data'][] = (int) $row['income'];
        }
    }
    $highcharts = json_encode($json_data);

    //return $json_data;
    //print_r($json_data); // Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => 1700 [1] => 5000 ) ) 

    //print_r($highcharts); // {"data":[1700,5000]}

    $this->load->view('reports/bqt_daily_income_view', $highcharts);
```

Comment: Second parameter of `$this->load->view` needs to be an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like:

```
$this->load->view('reports/bqt_daily_income_view', array('highcharts' => $highcharts));
```

In view file:

```
echo $highcharts;
```

#### Alternative post method:

```
$this->data['highcharts'] = json_encode($json_data);
$this->data['other']      = "bla bla bla";

$this->load->view('reports/bqt_daily_income_view', $this->data);
```

In view file:

```
echo $highcharts;
echo $other;
```

Comment: array('highcharts' => $highcharts) worked instantly. Thank you so much! Chart was drawn. :)

Comment: Your wellcome. If you want to post multi vars try `$this->data` method ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
$data['highcharts'] = json_encode($json_data);
$this->load->view('reports/bqt_daily_income_view', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to pass the array of data to the view and the keys of array will become the the variables accessible in views

```
function bqt_daily_income() {

    $json_data = array();
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT time_stamp,  SUM(paid) AS income  FROM payments WHERE type = 'Banquet Reservation' GROUP BY time_stamp ORDER BY time_stamp ASC LIMIT 30");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {
    $json_data['data'][] = (int) $row['income'];
        }
    }
    $highcharts['highcharts'] = json_encode($json_data);

    //return $json_data;
    //print_r($json_data); // Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => 1700 [1] => 5000 ) ) 

    //print_r($highcharts); // {"data":[1700,5000]}

    $this->load->view('reports/bqt_daily_income_view', $highcharts);
}
```

in view

```
<?php echo print_r(json_decode($highcharts)); ?>
```